# How to preload all my javascript files before loading my website body?

Tags: javascript, css, preload

This question have been already treated on the internet but i dont find a simple answer.

I would like to load only thoses javascript files and css, before starting to run the body my website.

I'm using packery.js, but when my website appears at first, my divs are misplaced. When i reload the page, everything gets back in place.

Is there a way to say : does all css and js files have been donwload? Yes? Ok run the body.

Thank you

Comment: The people want to see your info, not your code! The page should look good without js, and brilliant with it! Note that the most important feature of a webpage today is *loading time* , if you load all your js first, it wont improve that...

Comment: We'll need to see a minimal code example, the behaviour you want is the default behaviour if you have the scripts and stylesheets linked in your `<head>`.

Comment: @Jonasw, please try to stay on topic. You could as well tell OP: *"the people want to hear you speaking live. Delete your website and start doing seminars"*. While your comment/statement might be true, it's completely off-topic in regard with the question being asked.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you just need to move your scripts at the bottom of the 'body' tag.

Comment: You could load an empty page with all JS/CSS files (in your head-section) and load a new file with JS `ajax` command in your body part.

Comment: @andrei gheorghiu im not shure about that. If someone would ask *how to evaluate code the user inputted on serverside?* everyone would answer *its possible, but you dont want that* , i think its the same with this question. I would understand your criticism if i wouldve added this as an answer, which it isnt, its just a comment...

Comment: @Abedmori, the most common method to determine when all resources have been loaded (excluding async ones) is the [window.load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/load) event. You could, for example hide the contents of your page and display them on `window.load`. Most times the best and most efficient technique for dealing with [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) is loading the CSS for *"above the fold"* first, inside the `<head>` section of your page.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a lot of information you provided which would help us solve the issue directly, however couple of things...

Make sure all your scripts and styles links are places in the head tags. The HTML page gets rendered in browser Top-Down. I.E. It'll load any files from HEAD tags before the body is reached, same thing if you want your scripts to be loaded after the body is loaded.. just put them at the bottom, before the BODY closing tag.

Using JQuery would be the fastest solution if you wanted to perform some functionality after your page has loaded (I know there isn't a JQuery tag, however thought providing a JQuery answer could be advantageous.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   //Document Loaded, Put code you want to execute here.
}
```

Comment: This is quite wrong, @Adriani6. `document.ready` does not prevent FOUC from happening. Before answering questions on this topic you should make sure you understand the difference between `document.ready` and `window.load`. You might also want to link credible sources to your statements.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu OPs issue "I would like to load only thoses javascript files and css, before starting to run the body my website." Which, to my understanding is that he wants to manipulate a DOM element hence the question, he seems to be wanting to perform an operation after the body is loaded.

I.E. Load scripts so they are ready to manipulate the stuff, for which case, my example of document.ready is perfectly fit for this purpose.

JQuery Docs:
"Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute."

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu However, if my understanding of what OP is actually looking for in his vague question is wrong, $( window ).on( "load", function() {  }) would be probably more appropriate for him. Just to clarify, I have not mentioned any functionality of window.load, I stated "after page has loaded", not "after all linked files are loaded". which again, in document.load is a valid answer.

Comment: In general, it is better not to answer questions before having all the elements you need in order to provide a complete and correct answer. Use comments to ask for mode details when you need them. Indeed, at this point, it's unclear if OP is experiencing FOUC or not. But from their unclear description, that's what I understand: when resources are cached, page displays fine. When loading it first, it doesn't.

Comment: sorry guys for troubling you with my question. I dont want to perform a load of my css/js after the body is loaded. Ive uploaded a fake 50M js file to see how it behaves. The website takes a long timeto load the file, and the website is white. but the content of the body is only hidden as you u can see it when view the source of the page. I want to load my js files, and css files, and then load the body.

Comment: @Abedmori If your single js file is 50Mb, then you can expect it to take long time to load. I don't see any reason why one file should be as big but that depends on requirements I guess.

For that reason, have a look at window.load, this function will wait until all Scripts are loaded before executing any other functionality. 

It can be implemented in JQuery in the following order

$( window ).load(function() {
  // Run code
});